# How to compare a character to a number in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching

I'm trying to do it by pattern matching with the following

```
[x| x <- "example string", x > 106]
```

I know you can compare things such as `x > a`, and I'm guessing an explicit conversion is needed. One method to do this I found online but doesn't work is

```
[x| x <- "example string", ord x > 106]
```

And apparently doesn't recognise ord as a valid keyword.

Comment: you need to import `ord` from `Data.Char`

Comment: `ord` is not a keyword, it is a function from the `Data.Char` module.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[**`ord :: Char -> Int`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.1.0/docs/Data-Char.html#v:ord) is *not* a keyword, it is a function from the [**`Data.Char`** module](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.1.0/docs/Data-Char.html):

```
import Data.Char(ord)

myExpr = [x | x <- "example string", ord x > 106]
```

Here it might be more convenient to work with `filter`:

```
import Data.Char(ord)

myExpr = filter ((106 <) . ord) "example string"
```

both return:

```
Prelude Data.Char> [x | x <- "example string", ord x > 106]
"xmplstrn"
Prelude Data.Char> filter ((106 <) . ord) "example string"
"xmplstrn"
```

Answer (score 3):

If the number you are comparing to is a constant, you can always go the other direction: convert that number to a character constant, and then compare that to your characters directly:

```
filter (> 'j') "example string"
```